# How to get logged in users data (in a secure way)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework.
In my application I'm currently able to login and retrieve some data, but I'm not sure if the way I do it is a secure way.

**Here is how my application works:**

Currently when a user logs in, I make use of the following to store the username in a cookie:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, true);
```

Then I have a RoleProvider class that contains the following method, which returns a string array with the users role:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        List<string> rolesList = new List<string>();

        string role = CurrentlyLoggedInUser.User.Role.Name;

        rolesList.Add(role);

        string[] rolesArray = rolesList.ToArray();

        return rolesArray;
    }
```

Then I have the following class, that stores data of the currently logged in user:

```
public class CurrentlyLoggedInUser
{
    private const string UserKey = "MyWebApp.Infrastructure.UserKey";

    public static User User
    {
        get
        {
            MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities();

            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var user = HttpContext.Current.Items[UserKey] as User; //we set the 

            if (user == null)
            {
                user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Items[UserKey] = user;
            }
            return user; //Then we return the user object
        }
    }
}
```

Then whenever I need to query the database to find any related data of the user, I retrieve the users Id as follow:

```
int id = CurrentlyLoggedInUser.User.UserId;
```

Now I can make queries using this Id.

When I'm done, I logout and call the following:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Is this recommended and secure enough?

Comment: No. It’s extremely insecure. Anyone could set whatever username the want in their cookie and impersonate anyone. Writing an authentication system is HARD, why not just use one of the built in or prexisting ones?

Comment: I don't know anything about the build in/preexisting ones (haven't heard of them).  Do you have a link to read about it somewhere with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Consider requiring https to secure you login form, don't forget about `Authorize` attribute on your MVC controllers and/or actions (or, preferably set Authorize attribute as a global filter) and on the basic level that's enough. @Chad-Nedzlek is not absolutely correct, `FormsAuthentication`, you involve, takes care about your authentication cookie encryption, so it's not so easy for anyone to impersonate any other. But **you** have to take care about preventing bruteforce attacks when implementing your custom login: consider password lifetime limitation, required complexity etc.
And **if** you are thinking about future extensibility, SSO for web, mobile apps and API, or possibility of easy use of external (Facebook, Google etc) login, consider switching to OpenId Connect.